# How can I have a default onResponse for all my Retrofit2 calls?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

So I'm using Retrofit 2 to create all my API calls.

Here is some example code within my project. First for the Api.

```
public class Api {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.api.com/";
public static final String kApiUserLogin = "user/login/";
public static final String kApiUserRegister = "user/register/";

private static ApiInterface sService;

public static ApiInterface client() {
    if (sService == null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                .create();

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        sService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    return sService;
}

public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST(kApiUserLogin)
    Call<UserResponse> loginUser(@Body UserDTO userDTO);

    @POST(kApiUserRegister)
    Call<UserResponse> registerUser(@Body UserDTO userDTO);

}}
}
```

And then this is how I use it:

```
                    Call<UserResponse> call = Api.client().registerUser(user);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Response<UserResponse> response) {
                            UserResponse userResponse = response.body();
                            if (userResponse.getError() == null) {
                                UserDTO userDto = userResponse.getUser();
                                User.getInstance().setUserDTO(userDto);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                dialog
                                        .setTitleText("Error")
                                        .setContentText(userResponse.getError())
                                        .setConfirmText("OK")
                                        .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                            Log.d("CallBack", " Throwable is " + t);
                            dialog.hide();
                        }
                    });

                    Call<UserResponse> call = Api.client().loginUser(user);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Response<UserResponse> response) {
                            UserResponse userResponse = response.body();
                            if (userResponse.getError() == null) {
                                UserDTO userDto = userResponse.getUser();
                                User.getInstance().setUserDTO(userDto);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                dialog
                                        .setTitleText("Error")
                                        .setContentText(userResponse.getError())
                                        .setConfirmText("OK")
                                        .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                            Log.d("CallBack", " Throwable is " + t);
                            dialog.hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Now the question is how can I make it so that I can reuse a piece of code for the `else` section of `if (userResponse.getError() == null)` inside the `onReponse`? Bare un mind this is just an example. There are many api calls throughout the app, so it´s not like I just can make a method to be called below this 2 methods.

I was looking more for a default onResponse handler or something like that inside the Api class??

At the same time, I´d like to do the same for the `onFailure` of course.

Maybe I´m overcomplicating something very simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct, this would be enough.

```
   Call<UserResponse> call = Api.client().registerUser(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<UserResponse> response) {
            processResponse(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("CallBack", " Throwable is " + t);
            dialog.hide();
        }
    });

    Call<UserResponse> call = Api.client().loginUser(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<UserResponse> response) {
            processResponse(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("CallBack", " Throwable is " + t);
            dialog.hide();
        }
    });
}

    private void processResponse(UserResponse userResponse) {
        if (userResponse.getError() == null) {
            UserDTO userDto = userResponse.getUser();
            User.getInstance().setUserDTO(userDto);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            dialog
                    .setTitleText("Error")
                    .setContentText(userResponse.getError())
                    .setConfirmText("OK")
                    .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Ozgur, thanks your answer. I edited my question as soon as I posted and maybe you didn´t see my edit. I was mentioning that there are many api calls throughout the app in different classes. I was looking more for a default onResponse and onFailure handler or something like that inside the Api class??

Comment: I guess this is the simplest code block retrofit can offer. But I wonder the answer too.

Comment: If I don´t get a better answer within a week, I´ll just go your way and chose your answer. Thanks!